# How to get the Index of an element from an array using Arrays.asList

Tags: android, arrays

I got an arrray like this in android the usage of Arrays.asList is different because i made the Array with different class "Person":

```
 people = new Person[]{
            new Person("Python"),
            new Person("PHP"),
            new Person("Pascol"),
            new Person("PyCrust"),
            new Person("C"),
            new Person("C#"),
            new Person("C++")

    };
```

and i used  Arrays.asList in this way

```
 int index= Arrays.asList(people).indexOf("Pascol");
    String tags = Integer.toString(index);
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),tags,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But i get the value "-1"in the toast. 
i could not find the fault.

Comment: int index= Arrays.asList(people).indexOf(new Person("Pascol"));

Comment: You need to override equals() and hashcode() in Person class and send Person object with "pascol" instead of just string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [indexOf() will not find a custom object type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957813/indexof-will-not-find-a-custom-object-type)

Comment: @Nambari yep, we are right both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is  that you have a list of `Person` objects. When you call `.indexOf("Pascol");` you pass in a `String`. Comparing a `Person` with a `String` will return always false.Do this instead

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    if (people[i].getName().equals("Pascol")) {
        index = i;
    }
}

String tags = Integer.toString(index);
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),tags,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = Arrays.asList(people).indexOf("Pascol");
```

`Pascol` is a `String` here but objects in your array are `Person` type objects. So `indexOf` method can not match a `String` with a `Person`. You need to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` and pass a `Person` type parameter to the `indexOf` which name is `Pascol`. Of course I assume that equality of your object depends on only name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement Comparable<> in Person class