# How to set spinner selection if every field has key and value pair

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am updating a form in android fragment. In which i have spinner, i want to show default selected value in spinner but it is not working.I have searched a lot but nothing works. In function  TruckApi.getTruckCapacity("update_truck"); i have added data to truckCapacityList and it is showing in spinner but i am not able to pre select a spinner item based on truck_capacity_id.All solution tell about about get position.Any help will be highly appreciated.
here is my fragment code.

```
 package com.example.narmail.truckApp.Api.Fragments;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
        import android.text.InputFilter;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.Spinner;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.Api.TruckApi;
        import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.models.TruckModels.TruckBodyLength;
        import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.models.TruckModels.TruckBodyType;
        import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.models.TruckModels.TruckCapacity;
        import com.example.narmail.truck30mint.R;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        public class UpdateTruckFragment1 extends Fragment {
            Context context;
            Spinner truckCapacitySpinner;
            int truck_capacity_id = 0;

            public static List<TruckCapacity> truckCapacityList = new ArrayList<>();

            public UpdateTruckFragment1() {
                // Required empty public constructor
            }
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_update_truck, container, false);
                truck_capacity_id = getArguments().getInt("truck_capacity_id");
                context = getActivity() ;

                /*truck capacity spinner*/
                if (truckCapacityList.size() < 1) {
                    truckCapacityList.add(new TruckCapacity(0, "Select Capacity"));
                    TruckApi.getTruckCapacity("update_truck");
                }
                truckCapacitySpinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.truckCapacitySpinner);

                ArrayAdapter<TruckCapacity> capacityArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<TruckCapacity>(context,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, truckCapacityList);
                capacityArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                truckCapacitySpinner.setAdapter(capacityArrayAdapter);
                //  truckCapacitySpinner.setSelection(capacityArrayAdapter.getPosition(truck_capacity_id));
                truckCapacitySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        TruckCapacity truckCapacity = (TruckCapacity) parent.getSelectedItem();
                        truck_capacity_id = truckCapacity.getId();
                        System.out.println("on selected id is "+truckCapacity.getId()+ " and value is "+truckCapacity.getName());
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
                return rootView;
            }
        }

truck capacity has data like this 

    [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "500KG"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "1 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "2 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "3 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "5 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "7 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "8 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "9 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "10 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "12 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "15 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "18 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 13,
          "name": "20 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "22 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 15,
          "name": "24 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 16,
          "name": "28 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 17,
          "name": "30 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 18,
          "name": "32 TON"
        },
        {
          "id": 19,
          "name": "35 TON"
        }
      ],
```

here is TruckApi.getTruckCapacity("update_truck") function

```
         public static void getTruckCapacity(final String fragmentName){

            apiInterface = RetrofitApi.getRetrofit().create(TruckInterface.class);
            String token = User.getToken();
            System.out.println(" my token is "+token);
            Call<List<TruckCapacity>> call = apiInterface.getTruckCapacity(token);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<TruckCapacity>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<TruckCapacity>> call, Response<List<TruckCapacity>> response) {
                    Log.w("response is ",new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response));
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.w("response body is ",new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response.body()));
                        List<TruckCapacity> list = response.body();
                        for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                            System.out.println("i am in for loop ");
                            System.out.println("raw respone is "+response.raw());
                            if (fragmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("add_truck")) {
                                AddTruckFragment.truckCapacityList.add(new TruckCapacity(list.get(i).getId(),list.get(i).getName()));
                            }else if(fragmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("update_truck")){
                                UpdateTruckFragment.truckCapacityList.add(new TruckCapacity(list.get(i).getId(),list.get(i).getName()));
                            }
                        }
                       // System.out.println("truckCapacityList items are "+AddTruckFragment.truckCapacityList.get(2).getId());
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("error in response");
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<TruckCapacity>> call, Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println("error in getTruckCapacity is"+t);
                }
            });
        }
```

here is Truck capacity class

```
        package com.example.narmail.truck30mint.Api.models.TruckModels;

        import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
        import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

        public class TruckCapacity {

            @SerializedName("id")
            @Expose
            private Integer id;
            @SerializedName("name")
            @Expose
            private String name;

            /**
             * No args constructor for use in serialization
             * 
             */
            public TruckCapacity() {
            }

            /**
             * 
             * @param id
             * @param name
             */
            public TruckCapacity(Integer id, String name) {
                super();
                this.id = id;
                this.name = name;
            }

            public Integer getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(Integer id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            //to display object as a string in spinner
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return name;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if(obj instanceof TruckCapacity){
                    TruckCapacity c = (TruckCapacity )obj;
                    if(c.getName().equals(name) && c.getId()==id ) return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: U can use the custom adapter for the Spinner

Comment: TruckApi.getTruckCapacity("update_truck") Please share this method definition.

Comment: @PrateekBhardwaj i have added the code you require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simply, magic way to display custom object model in spinner

```
public class TruckCapacity {

        ...

        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return whateverYouWantToDisplay;
        }
    }
```

And a way to get selected item

```
TruckCapacity truckCapacity = (TruckCapacity) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

@Edit

You can for example search your spinners list to find searched id, loop iteration is an equivalent of your array position, and then programitically set selection

```
public int findSpinnerPosition(List<TruckCapacity> truckCapacityList, int searchId) {

        int position = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < truckCapacityList.size(); i++) {

            if (truckCapacityList.get(i).getId() == searchId) {

                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }
```

And select

```
int position = findSpinnerPosition(truckCapacityList, 7);
        if (position != -1) {
            truckCapacitySpinner.setSelection();
        } else {
            //item with this id doesn't exist
        }
```

Comment: ok grabarz121 but how can i get position because i have id only like i want to get selected spinner item where id is 7.means i don't have position i have only id

Comment: is there a way to do it without loop?

Comment: You can also override `public boolean equals(Object obj)` in your model class, and check statement that should return true. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24957871/5712938) a nice example, how you can do that. Then, in the final code, you can just use `int position = truckCapacityList.indexOf(new TruckCapacity(...))` what should return a right position, or -1.