# How to get the index of object by its property in Java list

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to get the index of an object in a list by its property in Java.
Example:

```
List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MyObj("Ram");
list.add(new MyObj("Girish");
list.add(new MyObj("Ajith");
list.add(new MyObj("Sai");  

public class MyObj {
public String name;
    public MyObj(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to the get the index of an Object which contains the name as "Girish". Please do let me know the code in JAVA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [search in java ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985229/search-in-java-arraylist)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [indexOf() will not find a custom object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957813/indexof-will-not-find-a-custom-object-type)

Comment: Why do you need to get the index at all?

Comment: Good question MC. Actually i would like to update that particular object when an update came from the server. Here server will give updates for individual objects only. So I have to search for the old object in my list and i need to update. At the end, i need all these objects in a list to do some analytics

Answer (score 21):

If you want a solution with stream use this one:

```
int index = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
     .filter(i -> list.get(i).name.equals(searchName))
     .findFirst()
     .orElse(-1);
```

Comment: There's a wrongly placed semicolon on the .findFirst() line.

Answer (score 6):

In case you have a `List`, all you can do is to iterate over each element and check required property. This is **O(n)**.

```
public static int getIndexOf(List<MyObj> list, String name) {
    int pos = 0;

    for(MyObj myObj : list) {
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(myObj.name))
            return pos;
        pos++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

---

In case you want to increase performance. Then you could implement your own data structure. **Note,** that key feature is that your key property should be a key of a `HashMap` and value of `HashMap` should be index. Then you get **O(1)** performance.

```
public static final class IndexList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
    private final Map<Integer, E> indexObj = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Integer> keyIndex = new HashMap<>();
    private final Function<E, String> getKey;

    public IndexList(Function<E, String> getKey) {
        this.getKey = getKey;
    }

    public int getIndexByKey(String key) {
        return keyIndex.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return keyIndex.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        String key = getKey.apply(e);

        if (keyIndex.containsKey(key))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key '" + key + "' duplication");

        int index = size();
        keyIndex.put(key, index);
        indexObj.put(index, e);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return indexObj.get(index);
    }
}
```

---

**Demo:**

```
IndexList<MyObj> list = new IndexList<>(myObj -> myObj.name);
list.add(new MyObj("Ram"));
list.add(new MyObj("Girish"));
list.add(new MyObj("Ajith"));
list.add(new MyObj("Sai"));
System.out.println(list.getIndexByKey("Ajith"));    // 2
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sorry, my fault. Fixed

Comment: In the comments OP said wants to return object . could you change ?

Comment: `Now, I would like to the get the index of an Object which contains the name as "Girish"` really?!

Comment: @manfromnowhere When you have the index, getting the Object is trivial

Answer (score 1):

indexOf() will work if you change the .equals function

I'd suggest just iterating through

```
int getIndex(String wanted){
  for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
    if(list.get(i).name.equals(wanted)){
      return i;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander. But is there any way without this loop? Because in my case there may be a chance of having 5k+ objects.

Comment: You could also consider using a `Map <String, MyObj>`

Comment: I tried but at the end, I need the List<MyObj>. How do i get the List from Map?

Comment: @GirishSetti Have you tried to do any research by yourself?  It is trivial

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have tried but the Map is giving the only util.Collections but not util.list.

Comment: As per my comment, the Map will contain a key (being the name) and the value beign the `MyObj` - there is no `List`

Comment: @GirishSetti If you absolutely need a list, you can do: `List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());`. If you need to keep the objects in the same order they were added to the map, you can use a `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score -3):

`indexOf()` will return the index of the *first occurrence* of a value.  For example:

`int myIndex = list.indexOf("Ram")`

(Note though that your arraylist doesn't contain "Ram", it contains an object of type `MyObj` with a `name` of "Ram")

Bear in mind ArrayLists start at 0 not one.