# Why is my index returning as -1 for a value that is within my list?

Tags: java

The goal is to modify elements within my objects, so my thought process is to first get the index of the object and then use said index to point me to the correct object to be modified.
I'm searching for the object using the name element within the object, but whenever I print the index to make sure it's collecting the correct one, I keep getting -1 for all names tried, even though objects exists with the name I'm searching for.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JAXBException {

        File file = new File("items.xml");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Items.class);
        Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Items itemData = (Items) un.unmarshal(file);

        List<Item> items = itemData.getItem();

        for(Item e: items){
            System.out.println("\nDataType : "+e.getDataType());
            System.out.println("Name : "+e.getName());
            System.out.println("Data : "+e.getData());
            System.out.println("Group : "+e.getGroup());
            System.out.println("Sub Categories : " + e.getItems());
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }

        System.out.println("'\n\n------------- Options ---------------");
        System.out.println("\n1. Search Items by Group");
        System.out.println("\n2. Modify Movie");
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        if (choice == 2){
            System.out.println("\nEnter the name of the movie you would like to modify: ");
            String search = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Index of: " + items.indexOf(search));
        }
```

Item Class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Item {
    private String dataType;
    private String name;
    private int data;
    private String group;
    private Items items;

    @XmlElement
    public String getDataType(){
        return dataType;
    }
    public void setDataType(String dataType){
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getGroup(){
        return group;
    }
    public void setGroup(String group){
        this.group = group;
    }

    public Items getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Items items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                "\n\tDataType: " + dataType +
                "\n\tName: " + name +
                "\n\tData: " + data +
                "\n\tGroup: " + group +
                "\n\tItems: " + items + "\n";
    }
}
```

Items class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "items")
public class Items {
    private List<Item> item;

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public List<Item> getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<Item> itemList){
        this.item = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + item ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of your `Item` class, especially the `equals` and `hashCode` methods? It's not clear how the `List` class will know that an item matches your search string, as you would need to write that logic yourself by (mis)using `equals`. Perhaps you want a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) rather than a list?

Comment: I updated the post with the classes

Comment: Yep, given the definition of `Item`, there's no way that the list `indexOf` method knows to check the `name` field specifically. Please give the use of a map a try ([this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-interface-java-examples/) may be helpful as a supplement to the link I sent above). The keys would be the names and the values would be the `Item` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `indexOf` of your `List<Item> items` with a `String` while it expects an `Item`. [See the official Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-)

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the *specified element* in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

To do what you want you could loop over the collection until you find the item that satisfies your search condition and then return the index. Something like this:

```
int findIndexByItemName(String itemName) {
  for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    if(items.get(i).getName().equals(itemName))
      return i;
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Would a filter be of any use in this instance? One used in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511107/how-to-get-the-index-of-object-by-its-property-in-java-list/54511232#54511232)

Comment: You mean the answer by @michal.jakubeczy? Yea that's the fancy `Stream` version of my solution :-) Functionally it does the same.

Comment: Cool, please don't forget to up/accept my answer. My last 2 cents: I don't know what your specific use case but I would be wary to use the `List`'s index for anything functional. The index is a technical detail of the underlying data-structure and may change or behave unexpected for a variety of reasons. You're already using a functional key (the name of the item) to search it, so there's no reason to get the index involved. If you need a *stronger* key, I suggest adding an explicit property to your `Item` class like `Id` or `Key` and using that instead :-)

Comment: I was under the impression that I using the index would be the better method from what I've read so far, but from what you said it makes sense to use the functional key to search alone. Any tips on how I can do what I want with using just the name? 2

Comment: Sure, something like `Optional<Item> item = items.stream().filter(x -> x.getName().equals(itemName)).findFirst()` and then you make whatever modifications you want to the item (if it's present)